# How can I Convert date from 'Mon Jun 05 2023 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time) to 'DD-MM-YYYY' in google APP Script

Tags: google-apps-script, date, time-zone

```
function onOpen() { 
const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
const menu = ui.createMenu('TRIGGER');
menu.addItem('create new doc' , 'createNewGoogleDocs');
menu.addToUi();

} 

function createNewGoogleDocs() {
const googleDocTemplate = DriveApp.getFileById('1l6GsQsIZ5XhfhWFi_RcX5ea-8Zh8DvGd28QugNxCeZo');
const destintionFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1Jzbk9pPAQTXRuvC9_5rFYoRIV0kbsf4c');
const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('CompletedForms');
const rows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();


const copy = googleDocTemplate.makeCopy('${rows[0]}, ${rows[1]}',destintionFolder);
const doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId())
const body = doc.getBody();

body.replaceText('{{Clinician}}',rows[1][0]);
body.replaceText('{{Date}}',rows[1][1]);
body.replaceText('{{Name}}',rows[1][2]);
body.replaceText('{{DOB}}',rows[1][3]);
body.replaceText('{{Address}}',rows[1][4]);
body.replaceText('{{EpisodeID}}',rows[1][5]);
body.replaceText('{{PresentingProblem}}',rows[1][6]);
body.replaceText('{{PhysicalExam}}',rows[1][7]);
body.replaceText('{{USSReport}}',rows[1][8]);
body.replaceText('{{Image1}}',rows[1][9]);
body.replaceText('{{Image2}}',rows[1][10]);
body.replaceText('{{Image3}}',rows[1][11]);
body.replaceText('{{Image4}}',rows[1][12]);
body.replaceText('{{Image5}}',rows[1][13]);
body.replaceText('{{Image6}}',rows[1][14]);
body.replaceText('{{Image7}}',rows[1][15]);
body.replaceText('{{Image8}}',rows[1][16]);
body.replaceText('{{Diagnosis}}',rows[1][17]);
body.replaceText('{{Injection}}',rows[1][18]);
body.replaceText('{{Drug1}}',rows[1][19]);
body.replaceText('{{Drug2}}',rows[1][20]);
body.replaceText('{{Drug3}}',rows[1][21]);
body.replaceText('{{Drug4}}',rows[1][22]);
body.replaceText('{{Reaction}}',rows[1][23]);
body.replaceText('{{Plan}}',rows[1][24]);

doc.saveAndClose();

}
```

Please guide, What I am missing as this is my first ever code.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

Use [Utilities.formatDate()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatdatedate,-timezone,-format), like this:

```
  // ...
  const timezone = sheet.getParent().getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
  const toDateString_ = (date) => Utilities.formatDate(date, timezone, 'dd-MM-yyyy');
  // ...
  body.replaceText('{{Date}}', toDateString_(rows[1][1]));
  // ...
```

Alternatively, in the event the data in the spreadsheet is already in the format you want to see in the text document, just replace `sheet.getDataRange().getValues()` with `sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues()`.

Comment: Thank you so much it did work for me.

Comment: I gather that this is your first question at Stack Exchange. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)